# In ASP.NET how can I dynamically add a formatting tag?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have the following on an ASP.NET page:

```
<li><asp:Hyperlink id="myHyperlink" runat="server">My Text</asp:Hyperlink></li>
```

Sometimes in code I need to be able to dynamically add a STRONG tag around the hyperlink so that it looks like this:

```
<li><strong><asp:Hyperlink id="myHyperlink" runat="server">My Text</asp:Hyperlink></strong></li>
```

Is there some elegant way to do this in code?  I know I could get it done using Literals but I just wondered if there was some special method that I didn't know about that allowed you to insert tags like that.

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: One clarification - I can't just set the hyperlink to be bold.  The CSS that I have been given and the HTML that I have been given require that the strong tag be around the A tag.

Comment: For the purposes of this question forget that the tag that I want to add is a STRONG tag.  Just think of it as any HTML tag.  The question is this - is there a way to dynamically add an HTML tag around a control?

Answer (score 3):

if this is something you're regularly needing to do, i would create a new server control and inherit the hyperlink control.  Add a property for Strong, and override the render method to add the tag if strong=true.  Note - this is not from an IDE so syntax might not be perfect

```
Public Class StrongTextBox
        Inherits Hyperlink

    Public Overrides Sub RenderEndTag(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

        MyBase.RenderEndTag(writer)
        If Strong Then
            writer.Write("</strong>")
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Overrides Sub RenderBeginTag(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

        If Strong Then
            writer.Write("<strong>")
        End If
        MyBase.RenderEndTag(writer)

    End Sub

private mStrong as Boolean
Public Property Strong as Boolean

   Get
                Return mStrong 
   End Get

   Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                mStrong  = value
   End Set

End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your li tag to runat server, like so:

```
<li runat="server" id="myLi"><asp:Hyperlink id="myHyperlink" runat="server">My Text</asp:Hyperlink></li>
```

you can add the strong tag like this:

```
var strongTag = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("strong");

Page.Controls.Remove(myHyperlink);

myLi.Controls.Add(strongTag);
strongTag.Controls.Add(myHyperlink);
```

As most others have noted though, use of STRONG is not really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a control that derives from HyperLink that renders an outer  based on a property, if the STRONG tag was a requirement (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

myHyperlink.Bold=true

Answer (score 0):

the Hyperlink element has a Font-Bold property that would do the same thing as adding a strong tag.

Comment: Actually it emits `style="font-weight:bold;"`

Comment: which will make it bold, same as a strong tag.